# how to handle prolog lists?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have the predicate `m(L,L)` and I want it to return the list that it takes.
The code is this :

```
m([],[]).
m([H|T],[H|L]) :- m(T,L).
```

When I try to use it with this example :

```
m([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],L)
```

I get this as an answer :

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

(I noticed that if I try it with less elements its ok.) why is this happening and the list is unfinished?

How can I avoid this?

Sorry if its a really stupid question but I've searched the web and I couldn't find any documentation that can help me understand...
Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: Your program is correct. It looks like a formatting issue in your Prolog environment, where it shortens long lists for display purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is finished - the output is just getting truncated for visualization purposes.  If you write a predicate that prints out your list, you'll see that it's complete.  I'm guessing you're using SWI prolog, which means you can check out [this link](http://old.nabble.com/To-make-Prolog-print-every-element-of-List-td1413274.html) for ways to change the display settings.

Answer (score 0):

Both the toplevel query/answer loop as the debugger abbreviate long complex terms. They do this to avoid endless pages of output. In fact, they write using [write_term/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_term/3) which takes an option-list as argument. The option list for answers printed by the Prolog toplevel is in the prolog-flag toplevel_print_options and the one for the debugger is in debugger_print_options. Initially both have the value given below:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, X).

X = [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(10), spacing(next_argument)].
```

To change the default settings:
Add a set_prolog_flag/2 directive in your prolog personal initialisation file (see [PlInitialisation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PlInitialisation.html)) to change the default the above mentioned prolog flags.

Just go to the `settings -> user init file ... ->`

And change max_depth(10) like this:

```
 :- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
             [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100)]).
```

There also other options you can use in **[PlInitialisation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PlInitialisation.html)** file that are commented already.